# html element background color not showing in IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, background-color

I'm using the `<body>` tag as a wrapper for three divs on a site where every single background color is white.

I've set the background color to #fff for the html and body in the css, and the site is rendering correctly in every browser (including IE 6 and 7) except IE8:

[image: Only one of the divs (the central content) is displaying its background color]

I've even tried setting the style for html directly inline like so: `<html style="background-color: #fff">` but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Not even sure what might be causing the bug.

Comment: Can you give us the code/website address please?

Comment: Sure:  I've posted the css and html for the page here: [http://jsfiddle.net/jDmtg/](http://jsfiddle.net/jDmtg/).  And to see it in action: [http://donaldjenkins.net/](http://donaldjenkins.net/).

Comment: Stephan Muller: Thanks for the suggestion.  The ones I haven't marked as answered is because, erm, none of the answers provided worked… xD  When a suggestion was helpful, I always voted it up.  But do let me know if I'm not doing the right thing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the following property in your CSS:

```
:focus{
  outline:0;
  background-color:#f2f3f6;
  border-color:#996
}
```

Apparently, on loading IE8 decides that the `html` element has focus, whereas other browsers don't do this. Remove the background-color property here and it'll all stay white.

Comment: Yeah, just guessed it was the one from his profile and I encountered the same bug in IE, so I whipped out Chrome's inspector :P

Comment: You beat me to it! I actually Google'd the OP, and conveniently found his site. I'd do another +1 for using Chrome's Inspector.

Comment: That did the trick.  Totally fixed: [http://cl.ly/5K2V](http://cl.ly/5K2V). Thank you *very* much. Now if only I could fix the right-hand sidebar that doesn't display inline in IE6...

Comment: Also speeded up my site's loading time, from 1.4 seconds to 1.3 seconds: sounds like that property was slowing it down a bit even in browsers that displayed it correctly.

Answer (score 4):

What happens when you insert this code into your HTML?

```
body div
{
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

Normally, browsers interpret and apply the last line of CSS that they read to an element, so `background-color: red; background-color: blue;` would result in a blue background color.

`!important` tell the browser to ignore all other property re-decelerations, so `background-color: red !important; background-color: blue;` would make the background color red, even though you told it to be blue.

Comment: Do remember though that this is just a means to check whether the `background: white` gets overwritten. It is bad practice to start using `!important` everytime a CSS property gets overwritten somewhere. The better way is (after having used !important to determine the problem) to find out where exactly it gets overwritten and then fix that.

Comment: I posted this just to see if it works (and if the author hadn't made another `!important` elsewhere). If I had access to the problematic page, I could just whip out Chrome's Inspector and tell you what rule is overriding the background color and where it is in seconds . But since I can't see the page, I can't help much at all.

Comment: I know, I was just adding to your answer, I even upvoted it. Just pointing out to Donald Jenkins that this is not a permanent fix, just a method of debugging :)

Comment: @Blender: Thanks for the suggestion!  I had tried it, obviously, though I don't like using it for the reason Stephan mentioned.  But it didn't work.

Comment: His suggestion worked totally and I immediately marked it as accepted: thank you both very much indeed.

Answer (score 2):

I think `background:#FFFFFF;` will fix it. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

internet explorer support 6digit color code  i.e. instead of #fff .. use #ffffff 
I hope you may understand this